# Allow Attribute constructor dependent on AttributeUsage

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes

I am having an attribute that can be applied either on a class or on a property.
This class does have two constructors. One accepting a type, one accepting a type and a string.

```
 [AttributeUsage(
        AttributeTargets.Property | 
        AttributeTargets.Class, 
        AllowMultiple = true)]    
class DcProxyAttribute : Attribute{
     public DcProxyAttribute(Type type){ /*...*/ }
     public DcProxyAttribute(Type type, string str){ /*...*/ }
}
```

I can use it like

```
   [DcProxy(typeof(SomeType)]
   class MyClass {
       [DcProxy(typeof(SomeType, "Hello World")] 
       public string SomeProperty { get; set;}
   }
```

I want to restrict it to this usage. It make only sense to use it like that.

The following usages are now considered valid, but they should not.

```
   [DcProxy(typeof(SomeType, "Hello world")]
   class MyClass {
       [DcProxy(typeof(SomeType)] 
       public string SomeProperty { get; set;}
   }
```

Can this be done?

I could create two separate classes for it. A `DcProxyForClass` and A `DcProxyForProperty`. And use it like

```
  [DcProxyForClass(typeof(SomeType)]
  class MyClass {
       [DcProxyForProperty(typeof(SomeType, "Hello World")] 
       public string SomeProperty { get; set;}
  }
```

but this kind of make the code less readable, since semantically speaking they do the same.

Comment: I'd create create a derived class from the attribute that can be used on the class declaration with the single parameter in the constructor and then limit the base attribute to property declarations.

Comment: I think the only reasonable way here is to use two classes.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that basically.

Options:

1. live with it, and raise an exception at runtime if the wrong overload is used
2. have two separate attributes, one for each (as you already suggest) - presumably using a common base-type attribute
3. live with it, but write a code analyzer (Roslyn etc) that detects the scenario and flags it in the IDE/build (presumably in combination with "1")